# Implementation of mergesort in C

Tags: beginner, c, mergesort

I have implemented mergesort in C. Any advice on making it more compact? My **merge** function seems less than fully optimal.

```
//mergeSort in C

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge(int [], int[], int[], int, int);
void mergesort(int[], int);

int main()
{
    int unsorted[] = {4, 1, 3, 0, 10, 2, 5, 5};
    int size = sizeof(unsorted)/sizeof(int);
    mergesort(unsorted, size);
    printf("The sorted array is: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", *(unsorted+i));
    }

    return 0;
}

void merge(int *original, int* first, int* second, int len1, int len2)
{
    int i = 0; 
    int firPtr = 0; 
    int secPtr = 0;

    while(i < (len1+len2))
    {
        if(firPtr == len1)
        {
            original[i] = second[secPtr++];
        }

        else if(secPtr == len2)
        {
            original[i] = first[firPtr++];
        }

        else if(first[firPtr] < second[secPtr])
        {
            original[i] = first[firPtr++];
        }

        else
        {
            original[i] = second[secPtr++];
        }
        i++;
    }
}
void mergesort(int unsorted[], int size)
{
    if(size <= 1 || unsorted == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    int *first = (int *)malloc((size/2)*sizeof(int));
    int *second = (int *)malloc((size - size/2)*sizeof(int));;

    int mid = size/2;

    for(int i = 0; i < mid; i++)
    {
        *(first+i) = *(unsorted+i);
    }

    //Common Error/Note to self: Make sure when initializing j to 
    //not 0, the code block truly requires that.
    for(int j = (mid); j <  size; j++) 
    {
        *(second+(j-mid)) = *(unsorted+j);
    }


    mergesort(first, mid); 
    mergesort(second, size - mid);
    merge(unsorted, first, second, mid, size - mid);
    free(first);
    free(second);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use `for` loop

This `while` loop in `merge` can be easily rewritten as a `for` loop:

> ```
> int i = 0; 
> // ...
>
> while(i < (len1+len2))
> {
>     // ...
>     i++;
> }
> ```

The benefit of a `for` loop is that it limits the scope of the variable `i`,
preventing misuses outside,
and it makes the `i++` easier to see, impossibly to forget:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (len1+len2); i++)
{
    // ...
}
```

#### Unnecessary recalculation

It's ironic to see `size / 2` repeated 2 times, and then again when storing in a variable:

> ```
> int *first = (int *)malloc((size/2)*sizeof(int));
> int *second = (int *)malloc((size - size/2)*sizeof(int));;
>
> int mid = size/2;
> ```

You could as well reorder these statements and reuse `mid`:

```
int mid = size/2;

int *first = (int *)malloc(mid * sizeof(int));
int *second = (int *)malloc((size - mid) * sizeof(int));
```

#### Naming

In `merge`, the variables `firPtr` and `secPtr` are poor names for two reasons:

- "Ptr" suffix is typically used for pointers. But these variables are not pointers, these are indexes. So the suffix should be "Index"
- "fir" and "sec" are meaningless fragments, simply spelling them out to "first" and "second" would make them naturally more readable

#### Pointer indexing

In some places you use array-style indexing with pointers:

> ```
> original[i] = first[firPtr++];
> ```

... while in many other places you use pointer arithmetics:

> ```
> printf("%d, ", *(unsorted+i));
> // ...
> *(first+i) = *(unsorted+i);
> ```

I suggest to use simply array-style indexing consistently everywhere.

#### Usability

As I pointed out on your other questions,
the program can become more interesting if it can take input from the command line rather than a hardcoded array.
You could rework `main` easily to that end:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int size = argc - 1;
    int * unsorted = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        unsorted[i - 1] = atoi(argv[i]);
    }

    // ...

    free(unsorted);
}
```

#### Minor points

No need for the `return 0` at the end of `main`.
The compiler adds that automatically.

The program doesn't print a newline after printing the sorted array.
This makes the output look strange when running in a terminal.
I suggest to add a newline at the end:

```
puts("");
```

Comment: i often get the suggestion to rewrite a while loop as a for loop and vice versa. What is the benefit of doing either one?

Comment: Hello, actually I am very conscious about your usability portion of the answer. I just didn't know how to take in an array as an argument, and figured it would be troublesome to do so, given the main purpose of the program  was to just do mergesort. However, thank you for your example on how to take in an array from the command line.

Comment: Lastly, I looked at the documentation for puts();. Looks so short and simple, why use printf in that case? Esp since puts appends a newline character for you also.

Comment: I explained the benefits of the `for` loop in the first section above. Use a `for` loop when a single incrementing/decrementing variable controls the loop, typically when iterating over elements of an array, or when counting to a target. Otherwise use another kind of loop. To learn much more, I recommend Code Complete's Chapter 16: Controlling Loops

Comment: As you mention, `puts` is simple, and that's both its power and limitation. It's fast because it's simple, but if you need to print something without a trailing newline, or use formatting, then you cannot use it, as it simply doesn't support these features.

Answer (score 2):

Taking memory into consideration:

That code uses \$(n*log(n))\$`sizeof(int)` bytes of **heap** memory for array elements storage.

This code makes it **n** `sizeof(int)`. By creating temporary memory only once and passing it to other functions, it saves significant memory in case of large arrays.

```
/* sorts given input array in ascending order */

void merge_sort (int * arr,int size)
{
    int *temp;
    if((temp = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size))!=NULL)
      msort(arr,temp,0,size-1) ;
}

void msort(int * arr,int * temp,int first,int last)
{
    if (first>= last) return ;

    int split = (first+last) / 2 ;

    msort(arr,temp,first,split) ;
    msort(arr,temp,split+1,last) ;
    merge(arr,temp,first,split,last) ;
}

void merge (int * arr,int *temp,int f_start,int f_end,int s_end)
{
                                /*    s_start == f_end+1      */
    int i = f_start ;
    int j = f_end+1 ;
    int k = f_start ;

    while (i<=f_end && j<=s_end)
    {
        if (arr[i]<arr[j])
            temp[k++] = arr[i++] ;
        else
            temp[k++] = arr[j++] ;
    }

    while (i<=f_end)
            temp[k++] = arr[i++] ;

    while (j<=s_end)
            temp[k++] = arr[j++] ;

    for (i=f_start ; i<=s_end ; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = temp[i] ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first post

Comment: You are missing a `free()`...

Answer (score 1):

When calling `malloc()`:

1. In C, do not cast the returned value.  It already has a type of `void*`, so can be assigned to any pointer.
2. Always check (`!=NULL`) the returned value from `malloc()` (and `calloc()` and `realloc()`) to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then a seg fault event will be raised due to accessing memory at address around 0.

Regarding this line:

```
int *second = (int *)malloc((size - size/2)*sizeof(int));;
```

There is a second (and unnecessary) `;` at the end of the statement.

You could save some CPU cycles by placing the line `int mid = size/2;` before the calls to `malloc()` and then using `mid` in the parameter rather than `size/2`. Also, a divide is (usually) an expensive operation. I suggest using `mid = size>>1;`.

Comment: However, if I don't cast return value for malloc, it gives me warning. (But yes, I am aware that it has return type void*)

Comment: But thanks for that bit shift reminder. I totally forgot that division is a pretty expensive operation. :)

Comment: @JonathanSmit,  What compiler and what parameters are you using to compile?   On my computer, running ubuntu linux 14.04 and using `gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c99` no warning is raised when the returned value from `malloc()` is not cast

Answer (score 0):

You can improve performance of `merge` a little bit. Also, using more elaborate names for your data won't hurt either. See a possible implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void merge(int [], int[], int[], int, int);
void my_mergesort(int[], int); // "my_" because gcc seems to contain "mergesort"

int main()
{
    // Your demo code.
    return 0;
}

void merge(int* original, 
           int* left_array, 
           int* right_array, 
           int left_array_length, 
           int right_array_length)
{
    int i = 0; 
    int left_index = 0; 
    int right_index = 0;

    while (left_index < left_array_length && right_index < right_array_length)
    {
        original[i++] = 
                left_array[left_index] < right_array[right_index] ? 
                    left_array[left_index++] :
                    right_array[right_index++];

    }

    memcpy(original + i, 
           left_array + left_index, 
           (left_array_length - left_index) * sizeof(int));

    memcpy(original + i, 
           right_array + right_index, 
           (right_array_length - right_index) * sizeof(int));
}

void my_mergesort(int unsorted[], int size)
{
    if (size <= 1 || unsorted == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    int mid = size / 2;
    int *first  = malloc(mid * sizeof(int));
    int *second = malloc((size - mid) * sizeof(int));;

    memcpy(first, unsorted, mid * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(second, unsorted + mid, (size - mid) * sizeof(int));

    my_mergesort(first, mid); 
    my_mergesort(second, size - mid);
    merge(unsorted, first, second, mid, size - mid);
    free(first);
    free(second);
}
```